# Serving http requests with tcpserver

Tags: http

I'm trying to use tcpserver from ucspi-tcp to launch a script that returns a simple web page. My script (hello.lua) is as follows:

`#!/usr/bin/env lua`
`print([[HTTP/1.1 200 OK`
`Content-Type: text/html`
`<html>`
`<head>`
`<title>My title</title>`
`</head>`
`<body>`
`<h1>Hello in big font</h1>`
`</body>`
`</html>]])`

I launch it with `tcpserver -v -rh 0 9000 /path/to/hello.lua`

When I use `tcpcat myserver 9000`, I get the expected return:
`HTTP/1.1 200 OK`
`Content-Type: text/html`
`<html>`
`<head>`
`<title>My title</title>`
`</head>`
`<body>`
`<h1> Hello in big font</h1>`
`</body>`
`</html>`

However, when I try to use a webbrowser and point to `http:\\myserver:9000`, I get a browser error (in Chrome) `Error 101 (net::ERR_CONNECTION_RESET): Unknown error`, even though the tcpserver logging shows a transaction:
`tcpserver: status 1/40`
`tcpserver: pid 21672 from <ip address of browser>`
`tcpserver: ok 21672 <server hostname>::::ffff:<server ip>:9000 <client hostname>::::ffff:<client ip>::3133`
`tcpserver: end 21672 status 0`

I know I'm missing something basic here, but I can't put the pieces of the puzzle together. Any insight is appreciated! Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need a blank line between the headers and the content:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Content-Type: text/html

<html>
<head>
<title>My title</title>
</head>
<body>
<h1>Hello in big font</h1>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 4):

[RFC2616](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec6.html#sec6) specifies that the status line and header lines of an HTTP response must each be terminated with CRLF. If you composed your lua script on a non-Windows machine, then you likely do not have the proper CRLF line-terminators. Also, you need to separate the message headers from the body with a blank line (a CRLF on its own).